# passing in parameters using param tag and flashvars param

Tags: flash, z-index, parameter-passing

I'm very new to flash and I don't intend on using it much I have just had to solve an issue (which seems age old) where the flash video on my page was sitting on top of everything else.

I read almost everywhere that the wmode parameter had to be set to opaque (some said it could be either opaque or transparent). When setting this through the flashvars parameter (this is in Chrome btw) this did nothing. After a while of getting frustrated, I added it as a parameter itself through addParam, and hey presto now it works.

Is this a simply a Chrome thing? FF it works seamlessly as it was. Even IE 7 and 8 are behaving slightly better. I wondered if this was a bug because supposedly adding a parameter to flashvars should do the trick.

I just wanted some clarity on the difference of  and the flashvars param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, the WMODE parameter is not a FlashVar at all, it's self-contained embed code parameter.

Have a look here: [Flash OBJECT and EMBED tag](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).

Comment: thanks. the thing is, the solution we were using already (nothing to do with me) was passing in wmode as a parameter for flashvars, and i imagine that was making it work in FF, so it must be listened to.

Comment: @Alex: It should never be passed as a parameter for flashvars. Flashvars is completely unrelated, FF or otherwise. You just use it as a normal object/embed parameter. If the code you investigated did that, it did so unnecessarily.